# Hide Points of Interest on Google Maps using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, google-maps

I would like to know how to hide the Points of Interest on a Google map using OpenLayers. I will include my sample code below that I have tried to use to do this but the parameters don't seem to work and the POIs still show. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Satellite Map with OpenLayers and Google Maps Platform</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script>
        var googleMapsSource = 'https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&style=feature:poi|visibility:off';

        var googleLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: googleMapsSource,
            })
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                googleLayer
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-95.995102, 41.257160]),
                zoom: 15
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you get that style setting from?

Comment: It comes from Google Maps static API and I'm afraid it won't work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the better way to do this.

First I upgraded OpenLayers to version 9.0, and then used the newly added Google source for my layers. This source allows passing parameters compatible with the Google Tiles API including styles, so I was able to successfully disable the POI markers! Modified sample code below for anyone needing it in the future.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Satellite Map with OpenLayers and Google Maps Platform</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.0/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v9.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
    <script>    
        var googleLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.Google({
              key: 'your-api-key',
              styles: [
                {
                  "featureType": "poi",
                  "stylers": [
                    { "visibility": "off" }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            })
        });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                googleLayer
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-95.995102, 41.257160]),
                zoom: 15
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```